# Why was this question Richfaces portlet | FacesContext not found closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

In my question [Richfaces portlet | FacesContext not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930384/richfaces-portlet-facescontext-not-found) I tried my best to explain the problem I was having. I provided maximum details like steps I performed and stack trace of the exception I was getting and believe that my question has a specific and authoritative answer. Then why it was closed?

Comment: "Can anybody point out what am I doing wrong here ? Any help, hints, pointers are appreciated." - that's slightly vague but the rest of the post makes up for it.  It's really the stack trace.  Isolate that down to the pertinent parts (don't just dump a stack trace like that on the site) and we can reopen it.

Comment: @casperOne Heh. Beat you to it... I don't think a stack  trace can be cut down if one doesn't know where the problem is in the first place.

Comment: @AnnaLear I think that it's possible to whittle it down.  If more of it is needed people will let the poster know.  Just dumping stack traces most of the time is lazy and inefficient when the pertinent information is in the top 10 lines or so.

Comment: @casperOne In principle, sure. In the context of this specific question... I think it's at least worth not being closed. A NARQ would usually be someone dumping a stack trace (or a giant code block) with a short "halp me fix my codez" type sentence. This question is a lot more clear than that and not deserving of a NARQ label, IMHO. If the stack trace is the wrong way to go, this can be resolved through edits/comments. Or it can remain unanswered if the requested clarifications are truly necessary and not provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you. Normally a large amount of code would be discouraged, but a stack trace is a stack trace. I don't see how you could cut it down without possibly losing important information that'd lead to an answer to your question.

I reopened the question.

I see there's also a request for a code sample instead of a stack trace in the comments. That might be a better way to go, but either way I don't think it's worth closing the question over it.

Comment: Remember that close reasons are there to help the user improve a post if there's not enough for a real question. As you said there's a request for code meaning that an incomplete picture has been given, hence NARQ.  Closure is what is done in this case to inform the user more work needs to go into the question.

Comment: @casperOne I'm aware of what the close reasons are supposed to do. But, this is a clear question with steps to repro and a comment asking for clarification. Hardly worth closing in my opinion, though clearly we disagree on that. I'd probably even let it stand if it was missing the stack trace but otherwise looked the same. (Edit: not a comment asking for clarification, but just a comment with formatting advice and a suggestion for a solution. Misread the first sentence in it.)

Comment: Thanks Anna. Actually it is not a request for code. I pasted my stacktrace in quotes rather then in code block at first. He is telling me to write stacktrace in code block.

Comment: @UmerHayat Oh yeah, you're right. My mistake, I misread that comment.